# Как отключить сброс высоты скроллинга ScrollViewer в TreeView при удалении TreeViewItem?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть TreeView, у него задано свойство ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto". Все нормально работает, но при удалении элементов из TreeView высота скролла сбрасывается.

Нашел [решение для похожей проблемы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30762007/scrollbar-resetting-to-the-top-of-the-treeview-after-sorting), но там для WinForms, как это сделать для WPF?